# urllib2 HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm 'loses' password after 5 requests

Tags: python, urllib2, basic-authentication

When sending email to the [mailgun API](http://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#sending) I have encountered a curious Python problem that I can't resolve: the PasswordMgr created by [`urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm) seems to lose the password after 4-5 attempts, and then I get 401 Authentication errors.

The same API key works later for later runs of the same code, so I am 100% certain that it is valid, and the whole thing works fine if I refactor the code to build a new `HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm` and `opener` within `Email.send_email()` (see below) for every submission to the API, but that doesn't strike me as a good approach.

I am creating the `opener` and it's `HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm` here:

```
class MailgunConnection(object):

    def __init__(self, domain, api_key):
        self.api_key = api_key 
        self.domain  = domain  ## https://api.mailgun.net
        self.opener  = self.mg_opener()

    def mg_opener(self):            
        passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()        
        passman.add_password(None, self.domain, 'api', self.api_key)
        auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)

        return urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
```

Once the opener is created by the following call, it is not created again or modified by the code:

```
opener = MailgunConnection(domain, api_key).opener
```

This `opener` is then passed to the `Email` classes created for each email

```
class Email(object):
    def __init__(self, details, opener):
        self.details = details
        self.opener  = opener
```

... and then used later in that same class's send method to send the email to MailGun's API:

```
def send_email(self):
    data   = urllib.urlencode(self.details)
    ## ... snips for brevity ...

    try:
        response  = self.opener.open('https://api.mailgun.net/v2/my.example.com/messages', data)
```

And it works... for 4 or 5 submissions... then I start getting a 401 error back from MailGun.  I'm sure it's not throttling from MailGun, nor an issue with the parameters I am passing, the same code works at first, and then later if the script is re-run.

Could anything else be happening that could affect the opener created by `urllib2.build_opener`?

This is on Python 2.6.8 on a CentOS 5 box.

**Additional Info:**
With more debugging, and a test of 15 emails, I can see that the server is responding in the same way to each request: with a `401` requesting authentication.  For the first 6 emails sent to the API, there is then a subsequent "resubmission" of the first request that invoked the `401`, which is accepted with a `200` and I receive the email.

However, after these 6 requests, `urllib2` stops sending the auth details to the server when requested - it just registers the `401` and doesn't resubmit the POST data to the API.

Comment: Consider using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of `urllib2`?

Comment: Yes, have considered, but I have 99% of this done with just standard libs, and wanted to avoid installing other things if possible...

Comment: Could you try to control what you are actually sending with a tool like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). I think we must first discriminate where the problem is.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Added some debug to the handler, and tested with 15 emails.  I can see that the server responds in the same way with a 401, and challenges the for auth for all attempts.  For the first 6 emails, urllib then responds with the authentication details, resends the POST data and all works.  All of a sudden though, the urllib stops responding to these 401 challenges and moves on to the the next email to be sent.

Comment: `requests` is just better.  Strongly recommended.

Comment: @AndrewGorcester Guess I'll just have to bite the bullet!  Thanks all the same..

Comment: @msturdy Good decision to try `request`. It is likely, you will remember the times using `urllib2` as being in middle age prison having to bite something very unpleasant all the time. Have a nice (Pythonic) age.

Comment: Just encountered the same problem with Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 'solved' by using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
r = requests.post(conf.email_api_gateway,
                auth=('api',     conf.email_api_key),
                data={'to':      self.email_add,
                      'from':    self.get_email_from(),
                      'subject': self.get_email_subject(),
                      'html':    self.get_email_html(),
                      'text':    self.get_email_text() })

## manually set UTF-8 so we can json the response
r.encoding = 'UTF-8'

if r.status_code == 200:
    mail_id = r.json[u"id"]
```

Comment: Are you using and old pre-2.x release of `requests`?  Current releases use `respone.json()` (a method, not an attribute) and handle encoding *much better* (correct RFC-compliant default to UTF-8 plus UTF codec auto detection).

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, it's version `0.13.1`.. will take a look at upgrading it.  Thanks for that!